# Newtonsoft Json Serialization just for specific property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've two classes and they have an aggregation relationship from one to another

```cs
public class Issue
{
    //---
    //tons of other properties
    //---
    
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }

}

public class Fields
{
     //---
     //tons of other properties
     //---
     
     [JsonProperty("customfield_10202")]
     public object Customfield10202 { get; set; }
}
```

taken a json result like this when I use json serializer with contract resolver

```json
{
 "customfield_10202": "value"
}
```

Here are the contact resolver and operation of serialization

```cs
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver("customfield_10202") });

public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;

    public DynamicContractResolver(string propertyName)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        
        properties =properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName == _propertyName ? true :false).ToList();

        return properties;
    }
}
```

but I expect result of json like this

```json
{
    "fields": {
        "customfield_10202": "value"
    }
}
```

I can solve this situation easy way but it doesn't seem right. how can I take a result of json that I mentioned without using a string variable

```cs
string json_data = "{ \"fields\": " + json + "}";
```

Comment: Did you try `properties =properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName== _propertyName || p.PropertyName == "fields" ? true :false).ToList();` ?

Comment: @EMRETUNA Could please share with us the `fields` variable assignment as well? Are you passing a `Fields` class instance to the `SerializeObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have the following `Issue` instance:

```cs
var issue = new Issue
{
    Key = "1",
    Fields = new Fields
    {
        Customfield10202 = "value"
    }
};
```

In order to be able to serialize

- `fields` from the `Issue` class and
- `customfield_10202` from the `Fields` class

you need to pass **both** names to the resolver.

So, instead of receiving a single `string` in the ctor you should anticipate a collection of `string`s:

```cs
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly string[] _properties;

    public DynamicContractResolver(string[] properties)
    {
        _properties = properties;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        return properties.Where(p => _properties.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

The usage would change like this:

```cs
var properties = new[] {"fields", "customfield_10202"};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(issue, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(properties) });
```

The generated output will be as desired:

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "customfield_10202": "value"
  }
}
```